# Does installation of rhdfs and rmr2 in master alone is sufficient, or those libraries needs to be installed in slaves as well?

Tags: hadoop, rhadoop

When using rhadoop, a set of packages for using R along with hadoop, Do I need to isntall the packages and Rscript in all the nodes seaparately, or else I just need to isntall it on the master machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that, we need to install the necessary packages on all necessary nodes manually, as there is no autmoated process avialable, apart from the good old shell script.